# Mysql query for finding word stored in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables search_words(id,word) and search_text_data(id,text)
I need to find the count of words from search_words which appear in the text rows in search_text_data
For eg. if the word in search_words is "family", then i want to find the count of how many times the word appeared in the text field in search_text_data

```
select a.id, a.word, count(b.id)
from search_words a , search_text_data b
where b.text like "%a.word%"
```

I know the above query is not the right syntax
Need mysql query syntax that would do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select sw.id, sw.word, count(std.id)
from search_words sw left outer join
     search_text_data std
     on std.text like concat('%', sw.word, '%')
group by sw.id, sw.word;
```